Writing a C++ concept for a class that has a method which takes an std::array of arbitrary size
Context
I'm writing numeric integrator as part of a library. As you might know, there are quite a few different types of numeric integrators (newton-cotes, gaussian quadrature etc.), and I'd like them to be interchangeable. Usually, one would do this by having and interface for an Integrator and then having some concrete types that implement that interface. However, my integrators need to be able to integrate functions of any arithmetic types (this is part of the reason why I'm writting it myself), i.e. they need to support double but also DoubleDouble and anything that reasonably behaves as a real number representation. Thus, I decided to write the integrator as a template class and have any other functions that need an integrator be template functions where the integrator would be a template parameter. I'd like, however, for this template parameter to be constrained by some Integrator concept.
Minimal Reproducible Example
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>

template<typename F, typename Ret, typename A, typename... Rest>
A
helper(Ret(F::*)(A, Rest...));

template<typename F, typename Ret, typename A, typename... Rest>
A
helper(Ret(F::*)(A, Rest...) const);

template<typename F>
struct GetFirstArgumentOf {
    typedef std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(helper(&F::operator()))> type;
};

template<typename F>
using GetReturnTypeOf =
typename decltype(std::function{ std::declval<F>() })::result_type;

template<typename F, typename T>
concept IsFunctionFromR = requires(GetFirstArgumentOf<F>::type argument) {
    [](std::array<T, 1>) {}(argument); //checks argument type (TODO should work for copy or const reference)
};

template<typename F, typename T>
concept IsFunctionToR = requires(GetReturnTypeOf<F> return_) {
    [](T) {}((T) return_);
};

template<typename F, typename T>
concept IsFunctionFromRN = requires(GetFirstArgumentOf<F>::type argument) {
    []<std::size_t N>(std::array<T, N>) {}(argument);
};

template<typename F, typename T>
concept IsFunctionFromRToR = IsFunctionFromR<F, T> && IsFunctionToR<F, T>;

template<typename F, typename T>
concept IsFunctionFromRNToR = IsFunctionFromRN<F, T> && IsFunctionToR<F, T>;

template<typename T = double>
class Integrator {
public:
    template<typename F>
        requires IsFunctionFromRToR<F, T>
    T Integrate(const F& f, std::array<T, 1> a, std::array<T, 1> b) const {
        return (b[0] - a[0]) * (f(a) + f(b)) / 2.0;
    }

    template<typename F>
        requires IsFunctionFromRNToR<F, T> && (!IsFunctionFromRToR<F, T>)
    auto Integrate(const F& f, std::array<T, 1> a, std::array<T, 1> b) const {
        constexpr int dimension = std::tuple_size<typename GetFirstArgumentOf<F>::type>::value;
        return [=](std::array<T, dimension - 1> y) {
            auto f_at_y = [&](std::array<T, 1> x) {
                std::array<T, dimension> argument{0};
                argument[0] = x[0];
                for(int i = 1; i < dimension; i++) {
                    argument[i] = y[i - 1];
                }
            return f(argument);
            };
        return Integrate(f_at_y, a, b);
        };
    }
};

int main() {
    Integrator<double> i;
    auto f = [](std::array<double, 2> x) {
        return x[0] + x[1] * x[1];
    };
    std::array<double, 1> a = { 0 };
    std::array<double, 1> b = { 1 };
    std::cout << i.Integrate(i.Integrate(f, a, b), a, b) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

The class Integrator has two Integrate methods: one for functions of one variable (std::array<T, 1>), that returns a T-valued scalar and one for functions of N variables, that returns a function of N-1 variable, where the first variable is integrated.
By the way, the use of a container which size is known at compile time is non-negociable (std::array in the question, in my actual code I use a class templated on the size N)
The Question
What I want to know, then, is if it is possible to write a concept for such an integrator, so that I may write:
template<IntegratorConcept I>
void DoSomethingWithIntegrator(I integrator);

I know that I can just write "typename I" instead of "IntegratorConcept I" and it will only work if the type I provides the necessary interface, but I'd like to know if that interface can be made more explicit through a concept.
What I Researched
I know I can't create an interface (aka pure virtual class) that is a template, which would solve my problem very elegantly.
The closest other idea I could find was this blog post, which starts trying to write a concept that uses another concept in the requires clause (which does not work) and then introduces the idea of archetypes. However, to make this work I would need to create an infinite number of archetypes, one for each dimension of the n-dimensional function.
Thanks in advance for the answers.

You would get more answers if you simplified your example, and making it more general, abstracting away all irrelevant details, there is no need to know what Integrator class is.

If I understand your question correctly, the difficulty mainly lies in the "arbitrary size" part. I don't think you can do it for actually arbitrarily large sizes, but if you have a constexpr maximum dimension for your integrand, the following solution should work.
First, let's define a helper struct that checks for the return type of Integrator::Integrate.
template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename ToCheck>
struct IsValidReturnTypeImpl{
    static constexpr bool value = IsFunctionFromRNToR<ToCheck, T>;
};

template <typename T, typename ToCheck>
struct IsValidReturnTypeImpl<T, 1, ToCheck>{
    static constexpr bool value = std::same_as<T, ToCheck>;
};

This means in the general case Integrate() should return another function that can be integrated, except when the dimension is 1, in which case the Integrate() should simply return a T.
Now we can define a concept that checks the return type for the Integrate():
template <typename ToCheck, typename T, std::size_t N>
concept IsValidReturnType = IsValidReturnTypeImpl<T, N, ToCheck>::value;

To really implement the concept you need, we also need a function to be passed as the first argument to Integrate(). Since it's only for concept implementation, the following will do. The operator() does not need to have an implementation.
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct testFunction{
    T operator()(std::array<T, N>) const;
};

Now we are ready for the real concept. To start, we fix the N and write the corresponding requires expression for it:
requires (const Integrator& integrator){
    {integrator.Integrate(testFunction<T, N>{}, std::array<T, 1>{}, std::array<T, 1>{})} -> IsValidReturnType<T, N>;}

This means the integrator should be able to integrate our test function with the two given boundaries and return a reasonable return type.
The next thing is to check this for other Ns. As stated above, it is not really possible to check for all Ns. However, it is possible to check up to a specific max dimension (maxSize), by using std::index_sequence:
template <typename Integrator, typename T, std::size_t maxSize = 255>
concept isValidIntegrator = 
    []<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
        return (
            (requires (const Integrator& integrator){
                {integrator.Integrate(testFunction<T, Is + 1>{}, std::array<T, 1>{}, std::array<T, 1>{})} ->
                IsValidReturnType<T, Is + 1>;}
            )
         && ...);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<maxSize - 1>{});

In the above code, a templated lambda is built which takes a pack of indices as NTTP. Inside the lambda, the corresponding parameter Is is used inside a requires expression, and a fold expression is used to collect the results.
Since std::index_sequence starts from zero, we need to use Is+1 instead of Is inside the lambda. For maxSize==255, Is+1 will then expand to 1...255.
Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/YshKxh673
